# Infinite Sum - Result not correct for all cases?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

Evaluating the `Sum`

```
Sum[a^i, {i, ∞}]
```

yields

```
-(a/(-1 + a))
```

which obviously only holds true for $\left|a\right|<1$. Why doesn't *Mathematica* give a limitation for the validity of the solution?

Comment: `Sum[a^i, {i, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]` will return the necessary conditions.

Comment: @J.M. OK, thanks. It seems as if I have to get used to MMA thinking more than I do ;)

Comment: It seems a conspicuous inconsistency to me that `Sum` has `GenerateConditions->False` by default , while `Integrate` has it `True` ( eg `Integrate[a^i, {i, 1, Infinity}]` ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @J. M. this solution gives the answer:

```
Sum[a^i, {i, ∞}, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

It returns a `ConditionalExpression`, in the above case:

```
ConditionalExpression[-(a/(-1 + a)), Abs[a] < 1]
```

Comment: In addition: look at `SumConvergence[a^i, i]`.